# Netbeans Bug Reporting on Maven Application

Tags: maven, customization, netbeans-platform

I have a Netbeans Application built via Maven. I have the following questions:

How can I include the Netbeans built-in bug reporting functionality on a Maven application?

How can I add a predefined JIRA instance on my Maven application?

How can I pre-define an update center on my application?

**Edit:**

Was able to find this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-bugtracking</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It adds the Versioning menu, but when trying to report an issue it gives an error when trying to add a task repository.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data for the combo-box.
    at org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.ui.selectors.RepositorySelectorBuilder.initializeCombo(RepositorySelectorBuilder.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.ui.selectors.RepositorySelectorBuilder.getComboBox(RepositorySelectorBuilder.java:244)
    at org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.ui.selectors.RepositorySelectorBuilder.createPanel(RepositorySelectorBuilder.java:320)

I assume that I need to add the JIRA support provider. Any idea?

Comment: I think it's all a matter of finding the right modules that provide the functionality and brand them if necessary. There should be docs on update center setup for sure.

Comment: Added some information after some progress.